# why there is an error of Authenting netlify account

Tags: netlify

Authentication Error
Authenticating failed due to the following error: We already have a registered user with this email address. Log in to connect your GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, all I did was sign up with my email again (as I has only signed up with my git account before) and still link to the same git account(github in my case) and it somehow got linked back.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34711661)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).